# 2 continuous variables with a categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Not sure what graph to use.

I currently have two density plots one for each continuous variable Vul and Glob against the categorical variable Continent which can be seen in dataframe below.

```
a = ggplot(Data,aes(x = Glob, fill = Continent)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.4) +labs(title = "Globalisation by Continent")

b = ggplot(Data,aes(x = Vul, fill = Continent)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.4) +labs(title = "Vulnerability by Continent")

grid.arrange(a,b)
```

```
 Country       Vul     Glob        Emm
1         Afghanistan 0.5963081 38.11748   9809.225
2             Albania 0.4227595 67.62799   5716.853
3             Algeria 0.3698284 56.07350 145400.217
4              Angola 0.5220609 43.27245  34763.160
5 Antigua and Barbuda 0.4864335 58.04864    531.715
6           Argentina 0.3681622 65.22942 204024.546
     EMMPC              GDPpc1 Code             GDPpc
1 0.299445 625.3395388+FF2:F55  AFG under-performing 
2 1.978763         4578.667934  ALB        performing
3 3.717410         5466.425778  DZA        performing
4 1.291328         5412.692348  AGO        performing
5 5.377649           12900.903  ATG        performing
6 4.746797         12245.25645  ARG        performing
      Continent  Latitude  AvgTemp Coastline ABSLatitude
1          Asia  33.83523 13.64797         0    33.83523
2        Europe  41.14245 12.70404         1    41.14245
3        Africa  28.15894 23.87725         1    28.15894
4        Africa -12.29336 21.97892         1    12.29336
5 North America  17.27750 26.27178         2    17.27750
6 South America -35.38135 14.84694         1    35.38135
  Coastline1 GDPPCLM  GDPpc000s
1          0       0  0.6253395
2          1       0  4.5786679
3          1       0  5.4664258
4          1       0  5.4126923
5          1       1 12.9009030
6          1       1 12.2452564
```

I would like one graph that shows both density plots or one graph to represent both continuous variables Vul and Glob against Continent.

Comment: If you stack your data, you can create a single faceted plot. Here's an example with the built-in `iris` data frame: `library(tidyverse); ggplot(iris %>% gather(key, value, -Species), aes(value, fill=Species)) + geom_density(alpha=0.4) + facet_grid(key ~ .)`. In your case, it would probably be: `ggplot(Data %>% gather(key, value, Vul, Glob), aes(value, fill=Continent)) + geom_density(alpha=0.4) + facet_grid(key ~ .)`

Answer (score 0):

I think `facet_grid()` would work very well in this case. But to generate graphs using ggplot (and `facet_grid()` in this case), making the original data frame tidy format would be really convenient (as suggested by @eipi10 as well).

```
 tidy_Data = Data %>% 
  gather(key, value, Vul, Glob)
 tidy_Data
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = key), show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(vars(Continent), vars(key), scales = "free")
```

I hope you find this helpful. If you want to know more about the function I suggest you check out [this official document](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

Comment: this worked but only shows density plot values for Vul I can't get image to upload to imgur of graph. Basically half the graph is perfect but I'm missing density plots for globalisation

Comment: I see. the reason is "Glob" variables are too small to show. Then how about simply add `facet_grid(~Continent)` to first two codes? such as `a = ggplot(Data,aes(x = Glob, fill = Continent)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.4) +labs(title = "Globalisation by Continent") + facet_grid(~Continent)`

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.